# Get the pushed ID for specific value in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrive the id that generated by firebase when I pushed value to it like next

[image: Firebase]

I want to retrieve "-KGdKiPSODz7JXzlgl9J" this id for that email 
I tried by getKey() but it return "users"
and when user get value it return the whole object from the id to profile picture and that won't make me get it as User object in my app

how solve this ?

```
    Firebase users = myFirebaseRef.child("users");
    users.orderByChild("email").equalTo("z@m.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.d("User",dataSnapshot.getRef().toString());
            Log.d("User",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            Log.d("User",firebaseError.getMessage() );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would you consider iterating over the users dataSnapshot and using an identifier value (like the email for example) to see if you have a match and retrieve the values of that matching snapshot?

Comment: yes to get the id that match this value

Comment: For next time: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment i will do that next time

Answer (score 28, accepted):

UPDATE 1: 
it can obtain also by one line

> ```
> String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
> ```

//**************************************************************//

after searching and trying a lot of things i came to 2 ways to do that 
.
 1. first one to get the key when i upload the post to the server via this function

```
 public void uploadPostToFirebase(Post post) {
      DatabaseReference mFirebase = mFirebaseObject
            .getReference(Constants.ACTIVE_POSTS_KEY)
            .child(post.type);
      mFirebase.push().setValue(post);
      Log.d("Post Key" , mFirebase.getKey());
 }
```

1. i used it in my code to get the key after i have already pushed it to node for it in my database

   ```
   public void getUserKey(String email) {

       Query queryRef = databaseRef.child(Constants.USERS_KEY)
           .orderByChild(Constants.USERS_EMAIL)
           .equalTo(email);

       queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //TODO auto generated
         }

         @Override
         public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //TODO auto generated;
         }

         @Override
         public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           //TODO auto generated;
         }

         @Override
         public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //TODO auto generated
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           //TODO auto generated 
         }
     });
    }
   ```

Answer (score 78):

You can read the key from push() without pushing the values. Later you can create a child with that key and push the values for that key.

```
// read the index key
String mGroupId = mGroupRef.push().getKey();
....
....
// create a child with index value
mGroupRef.child(mGroupId).setValue(new ChatGroup());
```

`mGroupId` contains the key which is used to index the value you're about to save.

Comment: This helped, even though I am using JavaScript.

Comment: But what if I have pushed the child already and later I want to get the key later? Is there any way to get that key?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Depends, is the child you have created is in the same operation as you need to read the key? then you can use this method, if it is in the different part of the code or if you need in the future, you can check out Frank Van's answer below

Answer (score 17):

When you fire a Firebase query there can potentially be multiple results. So when you ask for the value of a query, Firebase returns a list of items. Even if there is only one matching item, it will be a list of one item.

So you will have to handle this list in your code:

```
users.orderByChild("email").equalTo("z@m.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("User key", child.getKey());
            Log.d("User ref", child.getRef().toString());
            Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i know that but that doesn't answer my question 
for every child there exist a unique key for it i want to extract this Key 
if i use child.getKey() it return me "users"

Comment: Can you set up a jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: what do you mean by that  ?

Comment: @NandanKaushikDutta here is my answer to the question after i found how to solve it [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39492322/3553843)

Answer (score 8):

In Java - Android Studio, you can get the unique pushed ID as the item is written to the db...

> Per "Firebase's: Save Data on Android": You can use the reference to the new data returned by the push() method to get the value of the child's auto-generated key or set data for the child. Calling getKey() on a push() reference returns the value of the auto-generated key.

To get the reference at write time, instead of loading DATA with a single push()...

- use push() to create a blank record in the database, return value is the record's reference.
- use .getKey() to get the Key for that record.
- use .setValue(DATA) to fill in the blank record

here's an example:

```
    FirebaseDatabase fb_db_instance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
    DatabaseReference db_ref_Main = fb_db_instance.getReference("string_db_Branch_Name");

    hashMap_record = new HashMap<String, String>();           //some random data 
    hashMap_record.put("key_Item1", "string_Item1");
    hashMap_record.put("key_Item2", "string_Item2");

    DatabaseReference blankRecordReference = db_ref_Main ;   

    DatabaseReference db_ref = blankRecordReference.push();   //creates blank record in db
    String str_NEW_Records_Key = db_ref.getKey();             //the UniqueID/key you seek
    db_ref.setValue( hashMap_record);                         //sets the record
```

Comment: what happens if the object I want to save is not composed of string-only keys and/or values?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write demonstrates what kind of data that firebase can handle... it's all JSON, and includes String, Long, Double, Boolean, Map<String, Object>, List<Object>... the above example corresponds to Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 7):

I solved it to get id you need to use firebase url

```
String uid = firebaseRef.child("users").push().getKey();
Log.i("uid", uid);
```

this will give you the key `KG.....`

Answer (score 3):

For those using TVAC Tutorials(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSMMWOHkP68&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt&index=16)

You can get Key using onClick method as follows:

```
   viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           String key = getRef(position).getKey();

          }
     });
```

Comment: Worked for me! But only if you use FirebaseUI library

Answer (score 2):

Just add new field to Users like userID, when you create new User add uid and than you can receive it by reading query

I'm doing it like this.

```
String userID;// in Users


Firebase users = myFirebaseRef.child("users");
    users.orderByChild("email").equalTo("z@m.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users user= dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getValue(Users.class);
            Log.d("User",user.getUserID());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("User",firebaseError.getMessage() );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced this problem and I found the solution, 
you can get it using this code:

```
dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getKey()
```

Comment: thanks, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 // Unity, code in C#
{
 reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
 string s = reference.Push().Key;
 reference.Child(s).Child(Username).SetValueAsync(Username);
 Debug.Log(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to format the code using editing tools, and add explanation of how it works

Answer (score 1):

Another Option to get the unique Post-id from firebase is by getting key (**dataSnapshot.getKey()**) in  @Override method public void onChildAdded and maintaining it locally for example

```
private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mTaskEventListener == null) {
            mTaskEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Task friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Task.class);
                friendlyMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                System.out.println("friendlyMessage  = " + friendlyMessage);

                DummyContent.ITEMS.add(new DummyContent.DummyItem("" + DummyContent.ITEMS.size()+1,friendlyMessage.getStatus(),friendlyMessage.getSummary()));
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
                     mUserDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mTaskEventListener); // remove it
    }
}
```

dataSnapshot.getKey will set the unique post id in Task Instance and can be used later to perform any update operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users");
databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: key :" + key);

                    String email = dataSnapshot1.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String roomno =dataSnapshot1.child("address").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: email: " + email);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: address: " + address)
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: A little bit of explanatory text would improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 mFirebaseDatabase=mFirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tablename");
 Query query = mFirebaseDatabase.orderByChild("tablenme").getRef();


    query.orderByChild("Id").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String id =dataSnapshot1.child("Id").getKey();

                    String Name = dataSnapshot1.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                    String lastName= dataSnapshot1.child("lastname").getValue().toString();
                    flatDataGets.add(Name+"-"+lastname);



            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RagisterActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, DataGets);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mRegisterSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            mRegisterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  flatName =DataGets.get(position);


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }

            });

        }


            @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve the node or main child name by adding its name in that particular child as a key and value `{main_child_name}`.

Answer (score -1):

**Simply do similar:**

```
 HashMap<String, Object> hashLcl = new HashMap<>();
    hashLcl.put("admin", firebaseUser.getUid());
    hashLcl.put("name", textPrm);
    DatabaseReference referenceLcl = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String keyLcl = referenceLcl.child("GroupChats").push().getKey();
    hashLcl.put("key", keyLcl);
    Task task = referenceLcl.child("GroupChats").child(keyLcl).setValue(hashLcl);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
        //the data is added and now we are sure to do something related
    });
```

**This is the result:**
[image]