# How to retrieve the key in Firebase using Iterator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How to get the key in this json structure using Iterator?
The logic would be, if the user is **Harry Anderson**, I want to search the value from **person0** up to **person6** and if the value is found i want to get its key which in this case is **-KaSeO5n2xCl2sEnDpSi**. I don't know if this will be achieved using Iterator, but if there are other ways to do this, please do suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Refer the links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094631/get-the-pushed-id-for-specific-value-in-firebase-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232140/how-to-get-the-key-from-the-value-in-firebase

Comment: Thank you for the response but I could not find answers with the link. @Nainal

Answer (score 2):

```
 ref.child("chat/chat-participants").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("!_@@_Key::>", child.getKey());
                        keyList.add( child.getKey());
                }
              // your all keys are store in KeyList ArrayList
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("!_@@@_ERROR_>>", "onCancelled", firebaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference chatRef = database.getReference("chat").child("chat-participants");

chatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //do stuff iteration
    }});
```

I don't think there is an explicit method to do it