# Can't get key from FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pushing an object to `FirebaseDatabase`and trying to get the key of the object that I just pushed to `Firebase`. I've looked at [Get the pushed ID for specific value in firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094631/get-the-pushed-id-for-specific-value-in-firebase-android) and I'm trying to use that but it's not working.

Initialization of `DatabaseReference` in `onCreate`

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("People");
```

The actual function-

```
 private String pushPersonToFirebase() {

        Person newPerson = new Person();
        String firstName = mFirstNameTextView.getText().toString();
        String lastName = mLastNameTextView.getText().toString();

        if(!firstName.equals("") && !lastName.equals("")) {
            newPerson.setFirstName(firstName);
            newPerson.setLastName(lastName);
            newPerson.setImgPath(anonymousPeople.get(indexAnon).toString());
            mDatabaseRef.push().setValue(newPerson);
            return mDatabaseRef.getKey();  //This always returns "People" need it to return the key of the object that was just pushed
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the pushed ID for specific value in firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094631/get-the-pushed-id-for-specific-value-in-firebase-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can get key using this way..**

```
String key = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey(); // its your key
-- code---
newPerson.setFirstName(firstName);
newPerson.setLastName(lastName);
newPerson.setImgPath(anonymousPeople.get(indexAnon).toString());
--- code ---
mDatabaseRef..child(key).setValue(newPerson);
```