# How to edit the data inside the unique id of a child in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to implement a read receipt feature in my app...

Posting Data

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Send Blank Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
        String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
        messageTextBody.put("Message", messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("Seen", "False");
        messageTextBody.put("Type", "Text");
        messageTextBody.put("Time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageTextBody.put("From", MessageSenderId);

        DatabaseReference user_message_key = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).push();
        String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();

        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);

        mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now how do i access the "Seen = False" data which is inside a unique ID... i can access it through ValueEventListener but how do i make changes of that? i know only to fetch the data but i want to change the data of it... Can someone help me out please

Tried method

```
     DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child("Seen");
    seenRef.setValue("True");
```

I tried this above method but it just creates one more hild alongside it and sets its value to true.... someone please help me out... Thanks in advance

Database - https://ibb.co/js3iDd

Comment: Could you please add an image of your database?

Comment: Look to my edited question please

Comment: Well, from what I can see from the picture of your database, the `seenRef.setValue(True);` creates another path.
You are not accessing the same path for the message when updating the `seen ` property as you are when pushing the message in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method you are trying to use

```
 DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child("Seen");
    seenRef.setValue("True");
```

is replacing or overwriting your current value at that reference, i would suggest to make a map and use updateChildren to just update the value at the desired reference, also if you need to update multiple values at the same reference, this will save you multiple `setValues()`

```
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<String,Object>();
update.put("Seen", true);
seenRef.updateChildren(update);
```

but you can also do the same as you are doing without "" in your `setValue()` because you want to poot a boolean true or false inside it and you are sending a string "True" to the database , this will create a new key replacing/overwriting that same ref with the value `Seen : true`

```
DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child("Seen");
    seenRef.setValue(true);
```

Please check your seenRef, i just checked your db and i think is missing one more ref

[image]

so just change your ref

```
DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child(your_push_id_message).child("Seen");
```

in order to get your_push_id_message you will need to get that push id of the message to do that, first attach a listener to it and getKey()

```
seenRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

      String pushMessage = snapshot.getKey();
      dataSnapshot.child(pushMessage).child("Seen").setValue(true);



}

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Comment: That's right... how do i access that... what will 'your_push_id_message' be equal to... i mean i need to declare it but i dont know cuz its unique and automatically generated.. so how do i do that

Comment: you will need to create a value event listener and use getKey() in order to get the keys of each post, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094631/get-the-pushed-id-for-specific-value-in-firebase-android

Comment: also you will need to create your updateChildren or setValue inside this listener

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong because you are the directly updating value not with message-id which you generating for the message using push()

Here you doing

```
DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child("Seen");
    seenRef.setValue("True");
```

But you are not referring message id in which you need to do.

Like bellow

```
DatabaseReference seenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child(Message-Id).child("Seen");
    seenRef.setValue("True");
```