# How to retrieve data from Firebase to render lists in an app?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Studio. I connected Firebase to my app and am able to store data onto it along with the image. The data is like shown in the pic. I just want to know how can I retrieve all this data one by one in a list view or in such a view that it looks like items for sale. I don't know where to start coding.

I want output as a list where users can see items for sale :

Item Name - Laptop
Category - Electronics
Cost - 15000
Description - Good
Picture - ∆

..and then next item in list ..

How can I start on this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that this isn't a code writing service. If you have had a try, please edit the question to include your source code so far and to explain where you got stuck. If you genuinely don't know where to start, please edit the question to identify the documentation/articles you have read and why they didn't help. Thank you.

Comment: refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094631/get-the-pushed-id-for-specific-value-in-firebase-android Hope this link helpful to you

Comment: Thanks a lot, working on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/BlackBlind567/BeFirst/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blackblind/befirst/MainActivity.java) a link there you can find how to make a recyclerview but in this code I used a firebase firestore so there you can use firebase instead to firebase firestore.

Comment: is this useful for you?